# Applying filter to sum quarterly data

Tags: sql-server

I would like some help with the filter for summing `Quarterly` data.
For `Yearly` data I have added the formula.

For `Quarterly` data, I have hard coded for now but need to get the system to calculate.

So for example next quarter which will be `Quarter 3`, I need to calculate figures for current year/current quarter (summing figures for 3 months in that quarter)

SNIPPET of filter code

```
WHERE [Status] = 'Complete'
AND (YEAR([datefield]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
     OR YEAR([datefield]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2
     OR YEAR([datefield]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
     AND MONTH([datefield]) IN(4, 5, 6)) --Apr/May/June.
```

Comment: `datepart(quarter, [datefield]) = datepart(quarter, getdate())`? Alternatively just use `datediff(quarter, [datefield], getdate()) = 0`?

Comment: thanks but the 'Quarter' function doesn't work on my SQL

Comment: @Camille see my edit. the answer I provided earlier has problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for providing an incomplete answer. I have thought of this after I've answered.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE [Status] = 'Complete'
AND [datefield] BETWEEN CONVERT(date, DATEADD(M, -2, DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE())))
                AND EOMONTH(DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE()))
```

Explanation:

For the filter to be accurate, you need to get the first day and last day of the month.

**First Day:**

Get current date:

`SELECT GETDATE()`

> 2018-09-06 17:03:35.467

Get current date minus 1

`SELECT DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())`

> 2018-09-05 17:03:35.467

Subtract "current date minus 1" (the above result) to the current date.

`SELECT DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE())`

> 2018-09-01 17:03:35.467

Get date part only:

`SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE()))`

> 2018-09-01

**Last Day:**

Same as getting the first day, but changing `CONVERT` to `EOMONTH` since the latter already returns the result as `date` part only

`SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE()))`

> 2018-09-30

So you now have

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE()))
      ,EOMONTH(DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE()))
```

> 2018-09-01
>
> 2018-09-30

Get the previous 2 months from the current month.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(M, -2, DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE())))
```

Notice that I just added `DATEADD(M, -2, )` to the **First Day** value.

Combine the **first day** of 2 months ago and the **last day** of the current month you get

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(M, -2, DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE())))
      ,EOMONTH(DATEADD(D, -DAY(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())), GETDATE()))
```

> 2018-07-01
>
> 2018-09-30